# How to check if a object has ManyToMany reference in a queryset django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have these models in my django project

```
class Question(models.Model):
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField()

class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False)
    completed = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
```

I'm trying to find a optimized way for fetching a list of questions for user it should with whether they have completed it or not.
I think it can be done with these quersets:-

```
all_questions = Question.objects.all()
completed_questions = Question.objects.filter(profile = profile_instance)
```

where `profile_instance` is a profile object. Then we can loop through the `all_questions` and check whether they also exist in `completed_questions`, but i am not sure whether this is optimized for pagination. I'm using Django-Rest Framework pagination.

**Edit 1:-**
It looks like i'm not clear with the result i'm looking for, i will elaborate on it. I need a queryset which satisfies two requirements:-

1. List of all questions.
2. In this list, if let's say question 1 is completed by the user, then, it should have a boolean field turned to true. Note, that the question will only be completed for the current logged-in user not all the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to get the questions connected to the profile then something like this would work:

```py
completed_questions = profile.completed.all()
```

This will return a queryset of `Question` objects connected to that profile. There isn't then the need to loop through all of the questions to see if they exist in completed questions.

If you want to filter Questions to get all of those that are (or aren't) answered at all then you can filter for profiles with completed questions and then filter the questions against it:

```py
profile_with_completed = Profile.objects.exclude(completed=None)
completed_questions = Question.objects.filter(profile__in=profile_with_completed)
```

**Edit**

To get a list of all questions annotated with whether the question has been completed by the user or not, use the following annotation. It will check whether the primary key of each question is in the list of completed question primary keys connected to the selected profile (which you can separately linked to the logged-in user).

```py
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, BooleanField

all_questions = Question.objects.annotate(is_complete=Case(
    When(
        pk__in=profile.completed.values('pk'), 
        then=Value(True)
    ),
    default=Value(False), 
    output_field=BooleanField())
)
```

In your view or your template you can then access `question.is_complete` which returns true or false.

Comment: I edited the question to contain more clarity. Have a look at it

Comment: I've updated my answer, please take a look - does that help?

Comment: It looks like that is what it is needed but i'm not sure if it's optimized, but i believe using `prefetch_related` should optimize it.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that because `profile.completed` are also question objects

Comment: I tried this query and it's resulting in 29 queries for a 25 questions, `profile,completed` is hitting the database for every question.

Comment: Seems odd, I get a nice concise query when I try the code on similarly structured models - though there could be enough differences to lead to those extra queries. Does `prefetch_related` clean up the queries for you?

Comment: I tried this code, kindly take a look at it, https://codeshare.io/loOjxj

Comment: Your code is fine, the extra queries are related to another model which has ManyToManyField relation.  Thank you for your help